# How can I force a listview to draw its checkboxes as radio buttons in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, radio-button

I have a ListView and I have it *behaving* exactly as I want, I'm displaying check boxes and I'm only able to select a single item at a time.  Now the problem is this is bad UX- it shouldn't use check boxes when only 1 selection at a time is allowed, it should use radio buttons.  So I need to replace the checkboxes with radio buttons.  I think the easiest way would be to preempt the drawing of the checkbox and replace it with a radio button glyph, but I'm not really sure how to get started there.  Also, it needs to work on a ListView, not a ListBox, and it needs to work in WinForms, not ASP or WPF.  I would really appreciate information on how you know this as well- if you can link to documentation/code that shows how drawing works for the ListView in particular that would be wonderful.  I have found the docs for .NET 4.8 [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,c134a7877598504c) and am perusing that now, but details would still be appreciated.

So my question in brief is,  "How can I subclass a ListView (Not ListBox) to use radio buttons rather than checkboxes?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ListView.CheckBoxes` property is `true`, you could use the [`ListView.StateImageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.stateimagelist) property as a source for images of checked/unchecked items.

[Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.stateimagelist?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) says:

> The StateImageList property allows you to specify an ImageList that contains images to use to represent an application-specific state of an item in a ListView control. State images are displayed to the left of an icon for the item. You can use state images, such as checked and unchecked check boxes, to indicate application-defined item states. State images are visible in all views of the ListView control.
>
> **If an ImageList is specified in the StateImageList property and the CheckBoxes property is set to true, the images at index positions 0 and 1 in the ImageList are displayed instead of the check box. The image at index position 0 is displayed instead of the unchecked check box, and the image at index position 1 is displayed instead of the checked check box.**